# AlarmManager & NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am setting alarams as follows:

```
 AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60 * 1000, pintent);
```

Like this i am adding so many alarms with different time intervals.

So now i want to get next alarm time out of these.

For that i am using

```
  android.provider.Settings.System.getString(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED)
```

but the above is not returning any thing.

Pls some body help me ..

Answer (score 0):

`Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED` returns the next alarm of your clock, like it is shown on the lockscreen.

The `AlarmManager` does not provide methods for the next execution. If your using `AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating()` (saves battery!) it won't be possible to determine the exact time anyway.

Why don't you store the execution time in SharedPreferences or a database when you're scheduling an alarm?

Comment: Hi Gubbel, Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED will return only android alarm setted but not the alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,             calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60 * 1000, pintent);

Comment: That's what I wrote, maybe not clear enough though. You can't use this setting, because it has a completely different purpose. Also there seems to be no way to query the next alarm, so you will have to store the time yourself